# Calling DirectShow in Unmanaged code

Tags: c#, wpf, directshow, unmanaged

I am working on a C# WPF application which calls an unmanaged C++ DLL functions using PInvoke. The PInvoke functions are called from a WPF thread whose apartment state is set to MTA.
The PInvoke calls works fine.

The unmanaged C++ DLL uses DirectShow functions to create a window to show a video feed. For eg.  `CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED)` is called when a PInvoke function is called to initialize DirectShow. The DirectShow code works fine (no errors are seen). It is supposed to open a window and show the video feed. But the window does not open (it opens for an instant and then disappears).

Any idea why the direct show window isn't opening. Nothing stops me from opening a window from an unmanaged dll as far as I know.

EDIT: I get the same result when I call the DLL from a normal C# application (no wpf).

Comment: Creating a window on an MTA thread is always wrong, particularly so when you use DirectShow.  Not pumping a message loop (Application.Run) on a thread is a good way to make a window disappear after creating it.